# Pandas shift column data upon value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which looks like this:

```
    epochseconds  midPrice  midPrice_1
0     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
1     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
2     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
3     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
4     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
5     1570780800  2954.625         NaN
6     1570780800  2954.875         NaN
7     1570780800  2954.875         NaN

    epochseconds  midPrice  midPrice_1
24    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
25    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
26    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
27    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
28    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
29    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
30    1570780801  2954.875         NaN
31    1570780801  2955.000         NaN
```

Every epochsecond has different number of observations. I want to predict the next midprice at epochsecond+1. I wanted to apply pandas.DataFrame.shift, however this doesn't take into account that I have different observations for every second. Is there a way to take the mean of epochsecond:1570780801 and apply that to all observations of epochsecond:1570780800. I have 868471 seconds in total so this code should be applied to all observations.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can calculate the mean across all observations of the same epochseconds using `groupby` function, followed by `shift` (shift by -1 since you want the mean value of the current epochsecond to be applied to the previous epochsecond).

Then, you do a left join on the original dataframe.

```
df_mean_shifted = df.groupby('epochseconds')['midPrice'].mean().shift(-1).rename('midPrice_1')

df.merge(df_mean_shifted, left_on='epochseconds', right_index=True)
```

This will give you what you want, but you got to decide how to fill up the entries for the last epochsecond, which would be null (because of the `shift`).

```
    epochseconds    midPrice    midPrice_1
0   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
1   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
2   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
3   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
4   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
5   1570780800      2954.625    2954.890625
6   1570780800      2954.875    2954.890625
7   1570780800      2954.875    2954.890625
24  1570780801      2954.875        
25  1570780801      2954.875        
26  1570780801      2954.875        
27  1570780801      2954.875        
28  1570780801      2954.875        
29  1570780801      2954.875        
30  1570780801      2954.875        
31  1570780801      2955.0
```